# Google credentials actual json instead of path to file containing json

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, credentials, google-authentication

I'm developing a Web app and I'm using google translate so I set the environment variable - `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to point to the json file with all the secrets key.
Instead of path to file, I want to write the actual json like that:
[image]

Is there an option to do that? example? I read that you can do something like that with `GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS` but I didn't find any documentation about that.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can set a JSON Web token (JWT) like so:

```
const {JWT} = require('google-auth-library');
const keys = require('./jwt.keys.json');

async function main() {
  const client = new JWT(
    keys.client_email,
    null,
    keys.private_key,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'],
  );
  await client.authorize();
  const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/dns/v1/projects/${keys.project_id}`;
  const res = await client.request({url});
  console.log(res.data);
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

Obviously, you'd define `keys` inline rather than loading from the file. See also https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-nodejs#json-web-tokens.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to put key information inline. Even if it's possible, putting those directly into the code makes your code less flexible.

There is no such GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS environment variable on GCP.